# Has many relation design

Tags: database, database-design

I have products that have more than one size. Is the next design good?

- Product(#product_id, product_name)
- Size(#size_id, #product_id, size)

By '#' I denote a key, either foreign or primary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not clearly designated which column combinations are primary key and which are foreign key constraints and which are uniquely constrained in the Size table.

- Product_id is fairly obviously a foreign key referencing Product.  It presents no problem.
- Size_id is probably an auto-incrementing identifier, and is meant to be 'the primary key' for Size.  It seems like overkill to me, but isn't actually wrong.
- The undocumented combination of Product_ID and Size needs a unique constraint on it to ensure you don't end up with two rows like this:

  ```
  Size_ID   Product_ID    Size
   1234      23456        12
   1235      23456        12
  ```

That says the same thing twice — the product with ID 23456 comes in size 12.  And saying the same thing twice is repetitious and is apt to lead to incorrect answers (how many sizes does product 23456 come in — the answer is harder to calculate if you have to write COUNT(DISTINCT Size) instead of just COUNT(*), and not because of the typing but because the DBMS has to do more work, and because someone will forget sometime and produce the wrong query and it won't be spotted as a problem until the post-mortem examination of why something went dramatically wrong.

You could perfectly well do without the Size_ID, using the combination of Product_ID and Size as the primary key.  Failing that, you need a unique constraint on Product_ID and Size.

Comment: Do I need three tables Product,ProductHasSize and Size where ProductHasSize has as PK the product_id and size_id ?

Comment: It depends on whether you need to constrain 'size' values in the ProductHasSize table to be one of a small set of valid sizes.  If you do, then the three-table approach is reasonable.  The Size table would have columns Size_ID and Description (or thereabouts); the ProductHasSize table would have just two columns: Size_ID, a foreign key referencing table Size, and Product_ID, a foreign key referencing Product.  The primary key on the ProductHasSize table would be the combination of Size_ID and Product_ID (or, perhaps, the other way round).